# C++ error "X was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, scope, chess

so I downloaded this chess engine: http://www.ascotti.org/programming/chess/chess.htm

and I tried to compile & run it with eclipse...but then it displayed a whole bunch of error...

among them there's a lot of 'X was not declared in this scope' errors in multiple files including bitboard.h, hash.h, and pawnhash.h....

what does that error mean and how would you resolve these errors from these code?

also there's a lot of Uint64 has not been declared errors such as in bitboard.h...

again why is that the case, and how would you resolve it?

thx in advance

### EDIT: Error LOG

```
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\system.o ..\src\system.cxx
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\position_evaluate_pawn.o ..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx
In file included from ..\src\board.h:25,
                 from ..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:23:
..\src\bitboard.h:35: error: `bitCount' declared as an `inline' variable
..\src\bitboard.h:35: error: `Uint64' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:36: error: expected `,' or `;' before '{' token
..\src\bitboard.h:64: error: expected `)' before "lo"
..\src\bitboard.h:68: error: expected `)' before "n"
..\src\bitboard.h:85: error: `Uint64' has not been declared
..\src\bitboard.h:85: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `bb' with no type
..\src\bitboard.h:103: error: `Uint64' has not been declared
..\src\bitboard.h:103: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `bb' with no type
..\src\bitboard.h:107: error: `Uint64' has not been declared
..\src\bitboard.h:107: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `bb' with no type
..\src\bitboard.h:111: error: `Uint64' has not been declared
..\src\bitboard.h:111: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `bb' with no type
..\src\bitboard.h:223: error: `Uint64' does not name a type
..\src\bitboard.h: In copy constructor `BitBoard::BitBoard(const BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:73: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:73: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:73: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::operator=(const BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:82: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:82: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:82: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::operator=(int)':
..\src\bitboard.h:86: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:86: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::operator&=(const BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:91: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:91: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:91: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::operator|=(const BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:95: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:95: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:95: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::operator^=(const BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:99: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:99: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:99: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::operator&=(int)':
..\src\bitboard.h:104: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:104: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::operator|=(int)':
..\src\bitboard.h:108: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:108: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::operator^=(int)':
..\src\bitboard.h:112: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:112: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `BitBoard BitBoard::operator<<(int) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:116: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:116: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `BitBoard BitBoard::operator>>(int) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:120: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:120: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `BitBoard BitBoard::operator~() const':
..\src\bitboard.h:125: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:125: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `BitBoard BitBoard::operator&(const BitBoard&) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:129: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:129: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:129: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `BitBoard BitBoard::operator|(const BitBoard&) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:133: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:133: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:133: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `BitBoard BitBoard::operator^(const BitBoard&) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:137: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:137: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:137: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `int BitBoard::operator<(const BitBoard&) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:141: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:141: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:141: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `int BitBoard::operator>(const BitBoard&) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:145: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:145: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:145: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `int BitBoard::operator==(const BitBoard&) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:150: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:150: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:150: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `int BitBoard::operator!=(const BitBoard&) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:154: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:154: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:154: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `BitBoard::operator int() const':
..\src\bitboard.h:159: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:159: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::setBit(unsigned int)':
..\src\bitboard.h:164: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:164: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:164: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::clrBit(unsigned int)':
..\src\bitboard.h:168: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:168: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:168: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `int BitBoard::getBit(unsigned int) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:173: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:173: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:173: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::clear()':
..\src\bitboard.h:178: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:178: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::negate()':
..\src\bitboard.h:182: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `void BitBoard::andNot(const BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:186: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:186: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:186: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `unsigned int BitBoard::getRank(int) const':
..\src\bitboard.h:191: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:191: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `int BitBoard::isEmpty() const':
..\src\bitboard.h:196: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:196: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `unsigned int BitBoard::toByte() const':
..\src\bitboard.h:201: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:201: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `unsigned int BitBoard::toUnsigned() const':
..\src\bitboard.h:206: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:206: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `bool BitBoard::isZero() const':
..\src\bitboard.h:213: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:213: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `bool BitBoard::isNotZero() const':
..\src\bitboard.h:217: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:217: warning: unused variable 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In function `unsigned int bitSearch(BitBoard)':
..\src\bitboard.h:231: error: `Uint64' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:231: error: expected `;' before "b"
..\src\bitboard.h:232: error: `b' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:231: warning: unused variable 'Uint64'
..\src\bitboard.h: In function `unsigned int bitSearchAndReset(BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:238: error: `Uint64' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:238: error: expected `;' before "b"
..\src\bitboard.h:239: error: 'class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:239: error: 'class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:239: error: 'class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:240: error: `b' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:238: warning: unused variable 'Uint64'
..\src\bitboard.h: In function `int bitScanForward(BitBoard)':
..\src\bitboard.h:246: error: 'class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In function `int bitScanAndResetForward(BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:251: error: 'class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h: In function `int bitCount(const BitBoard&)':
..\src\bitboard.h:255: error: `int bitCount(const BitBoard&)' redeclared as different kind of symbol
..\src\bitboard.h:35: error: previous declaration of `int bitCount'
..\src\bitboard.h:35: error: previous non-function declaration `int bitCount'
..\src\bitboard.h:255: error: conflicts with function declaration `int bitCount(const BitBoard&)'
..\src\bitboard.h:256: error: 'const class BitBoard' has no member named 'data'
..\src\bitboard.h:256: error: `bitCount' cannot be used as a function
..\src\bitboard.h: In member function `int BitBoard::bitScanForward() const':
..\src\bitboard.h:260: error: `data' was not declared in this scope
..\src\bitboard.h:260: warning: unused variable 'data'
In file included from ..\src\engine.h:25,
                 from ..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:25:
..\src\hash.h: At global scope:
..\src\hash.h:118: error: `Uint32' does not name a type
..\src\hash.h:119: error: `Uint32' does not name a type
..\src\hash.h: In member function `void HashTable::Entry::packData1(const Move&, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
..\src\hash.h:71: error: `data1' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:71: warning: unused variable 'data1'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `void HashTable::Entry::packData2(int, int)':
..\src\hash.h:75: error: `data2' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:75: warning: unused variable 'data2'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `unsigned int HashTable::Entry::isUpperBound() const':
..\src\hash.h:84: error: `data1' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:84: warning: unused variable 'data1'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `unsigned int HashTable::Entry::hasSingleReply() const':
..\src\hash.h:88: error: `data1' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:88: warning: unused variable 'data1'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `unsigned int HashTable::Entry::hasMateThreat() const':
..\src\hash.h:92: error: `data1' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:92: warning: unused variable 'data1'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `int HashTable::Entry::getValue() const':
..\src\hash.h:96: error: `data2' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:96: warning: unused variable 'data2'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `int HashTable::Entry::getDepth() const':
..\src\hash.h:100: error: `data2' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:100: warning: unused variable 'data2'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `int HashTable::Entry::getBound() const':
..\src\hash.h:105: error: `data1' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:105: warning: unused variable 'data1'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `unsigned int HashTable::Entry::getSearchId() const':
..\src\hash.h:109: error: `data1' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:109: warning: unused variable 'data1'
..\src\hash.h: In member function `Move HashTable::Entry::getMove() const':
..\src\hash.h:113: error: `data1' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hash.h:113: warning: unused variable 'data1'
..\src\hash.h: At global scope:
..\src\hash.h:176: error: `Uint32' does not name a type
In file included from ..\src\engine.h:28,
                 from ..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:25:
..\src\pawnhash.h:95: error: `Uint32' does not name a type
..\src\pawnhash.h:96: error: `Uint32' does not name a type
..\src\pawnhash.h:97: error: `Uint32' does not name a type
..\src\pawnhash.h:98: error: `Uint32' does not name a type
..\src\pawnhash.h: In member function `void PawnHashEntry::setFlags1(unsigned int)':
..\src\pawnhash.h:71: error: `flags1' was not declared in this scope
..\src\pawnhash.h:71: warning: unused variable 'flags1'
..\src\pawnhash.h: In member function `void PawnHashEntry::setFlags2(unsigned int)':
..\src\pawnhash.h:75: error: `flags2' was not declared in this scope
..\src\pawnhash.h:75: warning: unused variable 'flags2'
..\src\pawnhash.h: In member function `void PawnHashEntry::setBlackScore(int, int)':
..\src\pawnhash.h:79: error: `blackScore' was not declared in this scope
..\src\pawnhash.h:79: warning: unused variable 'blackScore'
..\src\pawnhash.h: In member function `void PawnHashEntry::setWhiteScore(int, int)':
..\src\pawnhash.h:83: error: `whiteScore' was not declared in this scope
..\src\pawnhash.h:83: warning: unused variable 'whiteScore'
..\src\pawnhash.h: In member function `void PawnHashEntry::reset()':
..\src\pawnhash.h:87: error: `flags2' was not declared in this scope
..\src\pawnhash.h:87: warning: unused variable 'flags2'
..\src\pawnhash.h: In member function `unsigned int PawnHashEntry::isValid() const':
..\src\pawnhash.h:92: error: `flags2' was not declared in this scope
..\src\pawnhash.h:92: warning: unused variable 'flags2'
..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx: In member function `PawnHashEntry* Position::evaluatePawnStructure() const':
..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:169: warning: unused variable 'f'
..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:148: warning: unused variable 'zmax'
..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:149: warning: unused variable 'zmin'
..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:260: warning: unused variable 'zmax'
..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:261: warning: unused variable 'zmin'
..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx: At global scope:
..\src\position_evaluate_pawn.cxx:41: warning: 'char* sqname(int)' defined but not used
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 965  ms.
```

## EDIT

This is the content of platform.h where the define statements are:

```
#ifndef PLATFORM_H_
#define PLATFORM_H_

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define CDECL __cdecl
#define CACHE_ALIGN __declspec(align(64))
#else
#define CDECL
#define CACHE_ALIGN
#endif

#if defined(LINUX_I386) || defined(WIN_I386) || defined(MAC_G4)
// 32-bit platform
#if defined(__GNUC__)

typedef unsigned long long  Uint64;
typedef unsigned            Uint32;

#ifndef PRIx64
#define PRIx64  "llx"
#endif

#define MK_U64( n ) n##ull

#else // Visual C++

typedef unsigned __int64    Uint64;
typedef unsigned            Uint32;

#ifndef PRIx64
#define PRIx64  "I64x"
#endif

#define MK_U64( n ) n

#endif
#endif // 32 or 64 bit platform

#endif // PLATFORM_H_
```

and one of the files, bitboard.h where the errors appear:

```
#ifndef BITBOARD_H_
#define BITBOARD_H_

// Note: assembly code removed in version 0.6d

#include <stdio.h>
#include "platform.h"

extern CACHE_ALIGN const unsigned int lsz64_tbl[64];

/*
    Bit count function by Gerd Isenberg.
*/
inline int bitCount( Uint64 bb )
{
   unsigned w = (unsigned) (bb >> 32);
   unsigned v = (unsigned) bb;

   v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
   w = w - ((w >> 1) & 0x55555555);
   v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
   w = (w & 0x33333333) + ((w >> 2) & 0x33333333);
   v = (v + (v >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
   w = (w + (w >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
   v = ((v+w) * 0x01010101) >> 24;

   return v;
}

/**
    Bitboard, i.e. a 64-bit unsigned integer with some extra chess-related functions.
*/
class BitBoard
{
public:
    static const BitBoard   Clr[64];
    static const BitBoard   Set[64];

    //
    BitBoard() {
    }

    BitBoard( Uint32 lo, Uint32 hi ) {
        data = ((Uint64)hi << 32) | ((Uint64)lo);
    }

    BitBoard( Uint64 n ) {
        data = n;
    }

    BitBoard( const BitBoard & bb ) {
        data = bb.data;
    }

    //
    ~BitBoard() {
    }

    //
    void operator = ( const BitBoard & bb ) {
        data = bb.data;
    }

    void operator = ( Uint64 bb ) {
        data = bb;
    }

    //
    void operator &= ( const BitBoard & bb ) {
        data &= bb.data;
    }

    void operator |= ( const BitBoard & bb ) {
        data |= bb.data;
    }

    void operator ^= ( const BitBoard & bb ) {
        data ^= bb.data;
    }

    //
    void operator &= ( Uint64 bb ) {
        data &= bb;
    }

    void operator |= ( Uint64 bb ) {
        data |= bb;
    }

    void operator ^= ( Uint64 bb ) {
        data ^= bb;
    }

    BitBoard operator << ( int len ) const {
        return BitBoard( data << len );
    }

    BitBoard operator >> ( int len ) const {
        return BitBoard( data >> len );
    }

    //
    BitBoard operator ~ () const {
        return BitBoard( ~data );
    }

    BitBoard operator & ( const BitBoard & bb ) const {
        return BitBoard( data & bb.data );
    }

    BitBoard operator | ( const BitBoard & bb ) const {
        return BitBoard( data | bb.data );
    }

    BitBoard operator ^ ( const BitBoard & bb ) const {
        return BitBoard( data ^ bb.data );
    }

    int operator < ( const BitBoard & bb ) const {
        return data < bb.data;
    }

    int operator > ( const BitBoard & bb ) const {
        return data > bb.data;
    }

    //
    int operator == ( const BitBoard & bb ) const {
        return data == bb.data;
    }

    int operator != ( const BitBoard & bb ) const {
        return data != bb.data;
    }

    //
    operator int () const {
        return data != 0;
    }

    //
    void setBit( unsigned idx ) {
        data |= Set[idx].data;
    }

    void clrBit( unsigned idx ) {
        data &= Clr[idx].data;
    }

    //
    int getBit( unsigned idx ) const {
        return (data & Set[idx].data) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    //
    void clear( void ) {
        data = 0;
    }

    void negate( void ) {
        data = ~data;
    }

    void andNot( const BitBoard & bb ) {
        data &= ~bb.data;
    }

    //
    unsigned getRank( int rank ) const {
        return 0xFF & (unsigned)(data >> (rank*8));
    }

    //
    int isEmpty() const {
        return (data == 0);
    }

    //
    unsigned toByte( void ) const {
        return (unsigned)data & 0xFF;
    }

    //
    unsigned toUnsigned( void ) const {
        return (unsigned)data;
    }

    // Dumps this bitboard to the logfile
    void dump( const char * header = 0 ) const;

    bool isZero() const {
        return data == 0;
    }

    bool isNotZero() const {
        return data != 0;
    }

    int bitScanForward() const;

public:
    Uint64  data;
};

/*
    Bit search functions by Gerd Isenberg.
*/
inline unsigned int bitSearch( BitBoard bb )
{
   Uint64 b = bb.data ^ (bb.data - 1);
   unsigned int fold = ((unsigned)b) ^ ((unsigned)(b>>32));
   return lsz64_tbl[(fold * 0x78291ACF) >> (32-6)];
}

inline unsigned int bitSearchAndReset( BitBoard & bb )
{
    Uint64 b = bb.data ^ (bb.data - 1);
    bb.data = bb.data & (bb.data - 1);
    unsigned int fold = ((unsigned)b) ^ ((unsigned)(b>>32));
    return lsz64_tbl[(fold * 0x78291ACF) >> (32-6)];
}

inline int bitScanForward( BitBoard bb )
{
    return bb.data != 0 ? bitSearch(bb) : -1;
}

inline int bitScanAndResetForward( BitBoard & bb )
{
    return bb.data != 0 ? bitSearchAndReset(bb) : -1;
}

inline int bitCount( const BitBoard & b )
{
    return bitCount( b.data );
}

inline int BitBoard::bitScanForward() const {
    return ::bitScanForward( data );
}

#endif // BITBOARD_H_
```

Comment: Why are you building a foreign project with eclipse? Use the given Makefile and configure scripts...

Comment: What are the `#includes` from the files that cause problems? Are there any conditional compilation clauses like `#if` and `#ifdef`? Maybe the library is supposed to be compiled for a specific operating system?

Comment: could you post the lines from the header mentioned in the errors? Also, see where Uint64 is defined.

Comment: While I am delighted that you have accepted my answer, I did not provide a detailed solution (not knowing your exact build environment). Could you provide the details of how you fixed your issues to assist people finding this question in future (and also to satisfy my curiosity). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Uint64` and `Uint32` defined for your platform (you don't mention what that is in your question).

To do this you need to look at `platform.h`, in the included source.

It looks like you are using some version of GCC on some version of Windows, so *I suspect* all you need to do is provide `-DWIN_I386` to `g++`. I don't know how to do that with your build environment. Were you using the supplied `Makefile`, you'd take the following line...

```
CC_FLAGS = -Wall -DEOF_AS_INPUT -DGCC -DLINUX_I386 -O2
```

...and replace `LINUX` with `WIN`.

You'll find with that fixed, you have a more manageable list of warnings and errors. [sehe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608969/c-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-error/5609056#5609056) fixes one of the errors I encountered building with `i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)`. [Here is a patch](http://pastebin.com/EJgH2npx) showing fixes for my build.

Once you have fixed the code for your platform, you should send a patch to Alessandro Scotti.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the source and had to patch it in order to compile:

```
diff --git a/pgn_lex.h b/pgn_lex.h
--- a/pgn_lex.h
+++ b/pgn_lex.h
@@ -74,7 +74,7 @@ public:

         @return token identifier
     */
-    PGNTokenId PGNLex::getNextToken();
+    PGNTokenId getNextToken();

     /** Returns the current token identifier. */
     PGNTokenId tokenId() const {
```

Hope that helps

Comment: wait how exactly did you perform the patching...I'm not exactly familiar with the patching process...

Comment: I had to do something very similar: http://pastebin.com/EJgH2npx . @kamikaze_pilot: I patched it manually in my text editor.

Answer (score 0):

It means that an identifier used in the code was not declared earlier. It can be anything really a variable, a type name, something else. However if the code in question is expected to be valid then there is probably some library dependency missing. Check for the earlier errors. Among them there should be some "abc.h - No such file or directory". Also read about the required external libraries needed to compile the downloaded code and install them.